# Using Hk2 to generate an instance with the specified constructor args

Tags: java, dependency-injection, service-locator, hk2

I am using HK2 and the service locator pattern in my code. The following is the Interface:

```
package org.swx.nursing.tools.sqlfinder.gui;

import org.jvnet.hk2.annotations.Contract;
import org.swx.nursing.tools.sqlfinder.servicelocator.ServiceLocatorFactory;

@Contract
public interface GuiTemplate {

    public void createAndShowGUI(GuiTemplateCriteria criteria);

    public static final class Factory{

        //Disable public instantiation
        private Factory (){
            throw new AssertionError();
        }

        public static GuiTemplate create(){
            return ServiceLocatorFactory.getInstance().getService(GuiTemplate.class);
        };
    }
}
```

the following is the Implementing class for the above interface:

```
package org.swx.nursing.tools.sqlfinder.gui;

import org.jvnet.hk2.annotations.Service;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Service
public final class GuiTemplateImpl implements GuiTemplate{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7583852594722977867L;
    private static final Logger LOGGER      = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GuiTemplateImpl.class);

    private static GuiTemplateCriteria  criteria;

    public GuiTemplateImpl(GuiTemplateCriteria  criteria) {
        this.criteria = criteria;
    }
```

If I want to get an instance of the above class so that i can pass in the arguments for the constructor, how do i do that?

I know that the following would call the no-argument constructor & return an object with the Implementing class:

```
ServiceLocatorUtilities.createAndPopulateServiceLocator().getService(GuiTemplate.class);
```

The API is here: https://hk2.java.net/hk2-api/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/ServiceLocator.html

Please advise,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use @Inject on your constructor, like this:

```
@Service
public final class GuiTemplateImpl implements GuiTemplate{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7583852594722977867L;
    private static final Logger LOGGER      = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GuiTemplateImpl.class);

    private static GuiTemplateCriteria  criteria;

    @javax.inject.Inject
    public GuiTemplateImpl(GuiTemplateCriteria  criteria) {
        this.criteria = criteria;
    }
}
```

Comment: how would i pass in the argument object to this constructor if this object is being built using a builder in my main() method in another class? I guess @Inject will inject the implementing class but how do i pass in the object i want into the constructor or how would i create this in my main()?

Comment: You wouldn't create GuiTemplateImpl yourself.  That's what hk2 (or any DI container) would do.  GuiTemplateCriteria should also be an hk2 service, or there should be an hk2 factory that can produce the GuiTemplateCriteria for this to work properly.